# What should List____() in MVC controller return on user is unauthorized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have this code in my StuffController.cs

```
[HttpGet, Route]
[Authorize(nameof(Access))]
public async Task<ActionResult> ListStuff()
{
    var canRead = HasAccess(new AccessLevels
    {
        Stuff = AccessLevel.Read
    });
}
```

Since the return type of this function is ActionResult, what should it return if 'canRead' is false? I ideally want it to show a message (Something like 'You're unauthorized, please ask admin for approval') if the user tries to go to this page, but doesn't have authorization.

Comment: Why are you performing an authorization check *inside* the Action? You should have either Roles or Claims that you can check as filters before entering the Action.

Comment: could you elaborate more? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Your `AuthorizeAttribute` should be doing this, that's what it's for

Answer (score 0):

`401` is the status code for unauthorized responses.

One possible solution is to throw an exception with `401` status code with a message like the following:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(
  new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
   { 
      ReasonPhrase = "You're unauthorized, please ask admin for approval" 
   });
```

Another solution:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, "You're unauthorized, please ask admin for approval");
```

Another:

```
Response.StatusCode = 401;
return Content("You're unauthorized, please ask admin for approval");
```

Comment: this just showed on the browser as an unhandled exception. But that was in debug, maybe live it wouldn't?

Comment: @DylanYung Answer was updated, check if the second solution fits your case.

Comment: seems to cause it to loop now

Comment: Loop? How? It's just a return statement, how did it cause a loop?

Comment: Sorry I shoulda been more explicit. So I guess when you return HttpStatusCodeResult it keeps pinging that route. Which is what I meant by a loop

Comment: Another solution was added to the answer. However, when the response has 401 status code, the default behavior of your project is triggered which is usually redirecting to login page.